# Javascript: Mysterious lag on multiple runs of function

Tags: javascript, profiling

The following function simply returns an of elements with the specified tagname in the document. For some reason on successive calls to the function the execution of it gets slower and slower.. I have tested it thoroughly and the for-loop line in the cause, but I don't understand why that would cause a slow down on successive calls.

```
function getElementsByTagName2(tagName){
    var arr=new Array();
    var elems=document.getElementsByTagName(tagName);
    for(var i=0, len=elems.length; i!=len; arr.push(elems[i++]));
    return arr
}
```

EDIT: Changed variable names to please user257493.

EDIT1: Just tested jQuery and it has the same issue. The degradation is minor though.

Comment: Out of curiosity, if you leave this running for a long time, do you see a noticeable increase in memory usage of your browser?

Comment: Are you creating a new instance of the array with each call?  How many instances before it starts slowing down?  Have you considered jQuery?  It allows you to build sets of elements and operate against those sets - might be easier.

Comment: I don't quite get what this is doing. It seems to me the whole function body could be replaced with `return document.getElementsByTagName(e)`. Is it just supposed to be an example showing the slowdown?

Comment: http://www.objectmentor.com/resources/articles/Naming.pdf

Comment: @Jamie Wong: Memory usage is EXACTLY the same (according to the Chromium profiler). So strange..

@deceze: document.getElementsByTagName(e) returns a NodeList. I want an Array so that I can merge and sort through multiple Array's manually. This is purely for educational purposes, normally I would use Sizzle for something like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tested Your code and it seems to run just fine.

My results (iteration -> time taken (found divs):

**1. Firefox:**
0 -> 1524 (found 102)
1 -> 1534 (found 102)
2 -> 1518 (found 102)
3 -> 1528 (found 102)
4 -> 1535 (found 102)
...
15 -> 1513 (found 102)
16 -> 1512 (found 102)
17 -> 1513 (found 102)
18 -> 1513 (found 102)
19 -> 1518 (found 102)

**2. Chrome:**
0 -> 387 (found 102)
1 -> 283 (found 102)
2 -> 268 (found 102)
3 -> 272 (found 102)
4 -> 271 (found 102)
...
15 -> 270 (found 102)
16 -> 279 (found 102)
17 -> 267 (found 102)
18 -> 287 (found 102)
19 -> 272 (found 102)

Comment: hmmm.. something must be up on my computer or browser then!

Answer (score 0):

What goes on between the runs of your function?  How does the DOM change?  What's the likelihood that each takes successively longer because you've got an increased number of return elements?  Also, push is slow.  This also works and might speed you up a bit - I show no delays in repeated executions.

```
function getElementsByTagName2(tagName) { 
  var arr = new Array(), 
  elems = document.getElementsByTagName(tagName); 
  for (var i = 0, len = elems.length; i != len; arr[i] = elems[i], ++i); 
  return arr; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to assign the array elements directly, without push.

```
function getElementsByTagName2(tag, pa){
    pa= pa || document;
    tag= pa.getElementsByTagName(tag);
    var L= tag.length, A= [];
    while(L){
        A[--L]= tag[L];
    }
    return A
}
getElementsByTagName2('*',document.body)
```

Comment: Thank, that gave a bit of a speed boost.

Answer (score 0):

Does the Prototype to-array method have the same problem?

```
function $A(iterable) {
  if (!iterable) return [];
  if ('toArray' in Object(iterable)) return iterable.toArray();
  var length = iterable.length || 0, results = new Array(length);
  while (length--) results[length] = iterable[length];
  return results;
}
```